# Elegant way to show href based on condition

Tags: html, angularjs, anchor, href

I have to show an `<a>` tag. But depending on whether a value exists or not, I need to set `href`.

This is what I have:

```
<a ng-show="source.element!=0" "href="#/resource/{{source.a}}/{{source.b}}/val">
     {{source.element}})
</a>
<a ng-show="source.element==0" "href="">{{source.element}}</a>
```

If `source.element` is 0 , then nothing should happen on clicking on the value of `source.element`  (`href=""`)

Else, the page must be redirected according to the href.

Is there a better way to do this since this duplicates code?

Thanks..

Comment: Use ng-show out side of <a> tag for hide and show the whole tag. other wise if you want to change "href" , means use function to get source url.

Comment: @user3141852 FYI, using `ng-show` and `ng-hide` is less performant than using `ng-if`, because the elements and any expressions being watched stay in the DOM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create a method in scope

```
$scope.getUrl = function(source){
  return source.element==0 ? '#' :  '#/resource/'+source.a+'/'+source.b+'/val';
}
```

then call from view

```
<a ng-href="{{getUrl(source)}}">
     {{source.element}})
</a>
```

For angular markup it's better to use **[`ngHref`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)** .

Becuse if user click on href before angular load it'll go the wrong address.

Comment: Using [`ngHref`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) might be slightly better, but otherwise, same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is a small problem. When it returns `#` the url changes from `localhost:8001/#/something` to `localhost:8001/#`. Its behaviour is different from using `href=""`

Comment: @GregL thanks for mentioning ngHref. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @GregL i didn't write to hide

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi But it is not behaving like `href=""`. When I use `href=""` nothing happens when we click. But if I do as you told the page redirects to `localhost:8001`

Comment: for empty url it's recommend to use `#` or `avascript:;` or `javascript:void(0)` @user7

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi Using ng-Href while returning `''`works fine :)..  Btw I'm not the downvoter..

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-if

```
<div ng-if="source.element!=0"><a ng-href="your-url">{{sourceElement}</a></div>
<div ng-if="source.element==0"><a ng-href="">{{sourceElement}}</a></div>
```

[ngif Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-switch` to reduce the number of watches and code duplication:

```
<span ng-switch="source.element">
    <a ng-switch-when="0">
        {{source.element}}
    </a>
    <a ng-switch-default ng-href="#/resource/{{source.a}}/{{source.b}}/val">
        {{source.element}}
    </a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

```
$scope.source.url = $scope.source.element === 0 ? '' :  '#/resource/' + $scope.source.a + '/' + $,scope.source.b + '/val';
```

And in your markup

```
<a "ng-Href={{source.url}}>{{source.element}}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a directive with two attributes like `condition` and `url`:

```
app.directive('anchor', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            condition: '=expr',
            url: '@',
            prompt: '@'
        },
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: 'true',
        template: '<div>' +
                      '<div ng-if="condition">' + 
                          '<a ng-href="{{url}}">{{prompt}}</a>' + 
                      '</div>' +
                      '<div ng-if="!condition">{{prompt}}</div>' +
                  '</div>'
    };
});

<anchor expr="1 === 1" url="#/test" prompt="test" />
```

The [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/challenger/rbczrLx1/).